# How to iterate through xml in log files using Python

Tags: xml, logging, text

I have log files in which text and xml is mixed. I want to iterate through 'Poutcomes' to so that I can validate imformation recieved is as expected. For example I need to validate if AreadID for ItemId = 373012.

```
2019-09-12 15:30:02.137 (162,<ThreadPool>    ) Info          Sending:
<Keepalive />
2019-09-12 15:30:03.512 (65 ,Estate            ) DebugInfo     Incoming buffer has 292 bytes
<Poutcome>
  <ItemId>373011</ItemId>
  <AreaId>232</AreaId>
  <CarrierId>131</CarrierId>
  <AResult>
    <Measured>Ok</Measured>
  </AResult>
    <TimeStamp>2019-09-12T19:30:02Z</TimeStamp>
</Poutcome>

2019-09-12 15:32:02.137 (162,<ThreadPool>    ) Info          Sending:
<Keepalive />
2019-09-12 15:32:03.512 (65 ,Estate            ) DebugInfo     Incoming buffer has 292 bytes
<Poutcome>
  <ItemId>373012</ItemId>
  <AreaId>232</AreaId>
  <CarrierId>131</CarrierId>
  <AResult>
    <Measured>Ok</Measured>
  </AResult>
    <TimeStamp>2019-09-12T19:32:02Z</TimeStamp>
</Poutcome>

2019-09-12 15:30:06.559 (65 ,Estate            ) DebugInfo     Holding 0 bytes in buffer
2019-09-12 15:30:12.153 (149,<ThreadPool>    ) Info          Sending:
<Keepalive />
2019-09-12 15:30:16.561 (65 ,Estate            ) DebugInfo     Incoming buffer has 15 bytes
2019-09-12 15:30:16.561 (65 ,Estate            ) Info          Received:
<Keepalive />
```

I tried many xml ET but couldnt achieve because of text in between xml. I am trying Simplifiedscrapy now as suggested by someone, but it helps only to validate 1st part of logs, doesnt iterate to validate throughout log. How can I iterate to validate 2nd part of message (373012)? This is where I am now

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc

log_file_path = 'C:/Users/xx.log'

with open(log_file_path) as f:
    xml = f.read()
    #print(xml)
    doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
    Poutcome = doc.Poutcome
    #print(Poutcome.ItemId.text, Poutcome.DestinationId.text)
    if Poutcome.ItemId.text == 373012:
         print(Poutcome.DestinationId.text)
```

Comment: Is it always the same format? For instance, does incoming buffer always have 292 bytes?

Comment: @Jack Fleeting No, it varies. There are other messages in the log file as well

Comment: Then please edit the post and add a **representative** sample of the log. It would be difficult work without it.

Comment: @ Jack Fleeting Added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider cleaning up log file to keep only the XML markup. Below builds a string on every line of log except lines that start with `2019` and `<Keepalive />` (ad add others in the . Either create a new XML and read document with `parse` or directly read string in `fromstring`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with open('XMLinLog.txt', 'r') as fr, open('XMLinLog.xml', 'w') as fw:
    fw.write("<document>\n")
    xmlstr = "<document>\n"

    for line in fr:
        if line.strip().startswith('<'):
            xmlstr += line
            fw.write(line)

    xmlstr += "\n</document>"
    fw.write("\n</document>")

doc = ET.fromstring(xmlstr)
doc = ET.parse('XMLinLog.xml')

#...RUN NEEDED PARSING
```

**Output**

```
<document>
<Keepalive />
<Poutcome>
  <ItemId>373011</ItemId>
  <AreaId>232</AreaId>
  <CarrierId>131</CarrierId>
  <AResult>
    <Measured>Ok</Measured>
  </AResult>
    <TimeStamp>2019-09-12T19:30:02Z</TimeStamp>
</Poutcome>
<Keepalive />
<Poutcome>
  <ItemId>373012</ItemId>
  <AreaId>232</AreaId>
  <CarrierId>131</CarrierId>
  <AResult>
    <Measured>Ok</Measured>
  </AResult>
    <TimeStamp>2019-09-12T19:32:02Z</TimeStamp>
</Poutcome>
</document>
```

Comment: That sounds very helpful. But when the log file is like a million lines this wont be feasible when it has to run multiple times right?

Comment: Very important details to have mentioned. Solution reads each line one at a time and not at once with `readlines` from file and to string. It can also be modified to write lines one at at time as well. See edit.

Comment: Do you think you can answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63460177/parseerror-not-well-formed-error-for-some-special-characters-in-xml-data ?

Comment: See the [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63460177/parseerror-not-well-formed-error-for-some-special-characters-in-xml-data#comment112224183_63460177) by the XML guru (who writes books/software on XML). Find the encoding of your log file and add an `<?xml ... ?>` declaration with specified encoding before `<document>`.

Comment: I got that and I had added UTF-8 encoding on top. But the error persist on parsing. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try a combination of string manipulation and xpath - simplified version:

```
from lxml import etree
log = """[your log above]"""
#first clean up the log
snips = log.split(' bytes')
html = ''
for snip in snips:
    if 'Poutcome' in snip:
        html+=snip.replace('</Poutcome>','</Poutcome>xxx').split('xxx')[0]

#now to get the target
doc = lh.fromstring(html)
targets = doc.xpath('//poutcome[itemid="373012"]')
for target in targets:
    print(lh.tostring(target).decode())
```

Output:

```
<poutcome>
  <itemid>373012</itemid>
  <areaid>232</areaid>
  <carrierid>131</carrierid>
  <aresult>
    <measured>Ok</measured>
  </aresult>
    <timestamp>2019-09-12T19:32:02Z</timestamp>
</poutcome>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as follows.

```
log_file_path = 'C:/Users/xx.log'

with open(log_file_path) as f:
    xml = f.read()
    #print(xml)
    doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
    Poutcomes = doc.Poutcomes # Suffix plus s means to take all data
    for Poutcome in Poutcomes:
        #print(Poutcome.ItemId.text, Poutcome.DestinationId.text)
        if Poutcome.ItemId.text == '373012': # text is string
            print(Poutcome.DestinationId.text)
```

If you only want data with a value of 373012, you can use the following method.

```
with open(log_file_path) as f:
    xml = f.read()
    #print(xml)
    doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
    ItemId = doc.getElementByText("373012",tag="ItemId")
    print (ItemId.text)
    Poutcome = ItemId.parent
    print (Poutcome.AreaId.text)
```

If your log file is too large to be loaded into memory at one time, it can be read in blocks. The code is as follows.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
def getPoutcome(lines,id):
  html = "".join(lines)
  Poutcome = SimplifiedDoc(html).Poutcome
  if Poutcome.ItemId.text==id:
    return Poutcome
lst = []
log_file_path = 'xx.log'
with open(log_file_path, 'r') as file: # xx.log is your log file path
  lines = []
  flag = False
  for line in file:
    if flag or line.find('<Poutcome')>=0:
      flag = True
      lines.append(line)
    if line.find('</Poutcome>')>=0:
      b = getPoutcome(lines,'373012')
      if b: 
        lst.append(b.ItemId.text)
        break # If you only want the first one, add a break
      flag = False
      lines = []
print (lst)
```

If there is a problem with the above code, it is possible that your s version is too low. Try updating it. pip3 install -U simplified_scrapy