# 'ParseError: not well-formed' Error for some Special characters in XML Data

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have the following code to cleanup the log file to get XML out of it (log file is not well formatted and doesn't have root) and then parse and perform other functions. Clean up works, but But XML Parser is throwing me error for some xml data which contain some special characters. My code is as below:

```
with open(log_file, 'r') as fr, open('XMLinLog2.xml', 'w') as fw:
    fw.write("<document>\n")

    for line in fr:
        if line.strip().startswith('<'):
            fw.write('\t' + line)
    fw.write("\n</document>")

# --- Parsing Log files after cleanup ---

doc = ET.parse('XMLinLog2.xml')
```

The xml data in log file which throws me error is for;
(1) **Ops Désactivée 23:59** and (2) **[ mono @ 90° >> +1**
which after cleanup in the log file is shown as **Ops D�sactiv�e 23:59** and **[ mono @ 90� >> +1** respectively.
So I figured out � character is causing issues.
Question:

1. How do I deal with this error?
2. If I need to print the those data, how can I print them correctly? I dont want to print �.  Because I assume it will throw error whenever I have french text coming in for é .

Full error here:
raceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/IMSS_TestHarness/Libraries/try.py", line 23, in 
doc = ET.parse('XMLinLog2.xml')
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1202, in parse
tree.parse(source, parser)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 595, in parse
self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 3299, column 22

Process finished with exit code 1

Log file:

```
1.  2020-08-03 15:59:54.635 (72 ,Effective Commit) Info          Sending:
<U_DisplayCommand>
  <DestinationId>5035</DestinationId>
  <DisplayId>1</DisplayId>
  <LineTextEnglish>
    <Line>Ops Disabled 23:59 N</Line>
  </LineTextEnglish>
  <LineTextFrench>
    **<Line>Ops Désactivée 23:59</Line>**
  </LineTextFrench>
</U_DisplayCommand>
```

2. 

```
<U_DisplayCommand>
  <DestinationId>5085</DestinationId>
  <DisplayId>1</DisplayId>
  <LineTextEnglish>
    <Line>Vaudreuil-Dori P123A</Line>
    <Line>[ mono @ 90° &gt;&gt; +1</Line>
  </LineTextEnglish>
  <LineTextFrench>
    <Line>Vaudreuil-Dori P123A</Line>
    <Line>[ mono @ 90° &gt;&gt; +1</Line>
  </LineTextFrench>
</U_DisplayCommand>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basically, you need to make sure that the file has an encoding declaration at the start (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="...."?>`) and that the declared encoding matches the actual encoding of the characters written to the file.

Comment: Please post sample of log file for [mcve]. There are a number of [entities that must be escaped in XML](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xml/xml_character_entities.htm).

Comment: Just added logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually adding encoding worked for me.

```
with open(log_file, 'r') as fr, open('XMLinLog2.xml', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fw:
    fw.write("<document>\n")

    for line in fr:
        if line.strip().startswith('<'):
            fw.write('\t' + line)
    fw.write("\n</document>")

# --- Parsing Log files after cleanup ---

doc = ET.parse('XMLinLog2.xml')
```